# Transfer Ether from contract to user addresses

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-price, gas-limit, internal-transactions

I have code to transfer Ether to an address, as follows:

```
addr.transfer(amount);
```

Unfortunately, when I execute this statement for two transfers, the money never arrives in the `addr` addresses. I do see the Etherscan output on Ropsten:

[image]

I have a suspicion the transfers (call_1_0 and call_1_1 below) are never fulfilled, because the GasLimit is set to 2300. Is this possible?

Is there a way to increase the GasLimit? I tried using:

```
  uint GAS_LIMIT = 4000000;
  addr.transfer.gas(GAS_LIMIT)(amount);
```

but then the `solc` compiler says:

> TypeError: Member "gas" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function (uint256)
>         addr.transfer.gas(GAS_LIMIT)(amount);
>         ^---------------^

This is the full code of the contract (beneficiaries are added during construction by a "manager" contract that instantiates it.

```
contract SimpleSmartAsset is Mortal {

  uint usagePrice;
  Beneficiary[] beneficiaries;
  uint totalWeight; // to calculate percentage the beneficiaries receive

  event AssetCreated(uint _usagePrice,
                     address[] addresses,
                     uint[] weights);

  function SimpleSmartAsset(uint _usagePrice,
                            address[] addresses,
                            uint[] weights) {
    owner = msg.sender;
    usagePrice = _usagePrice;

    uint beneficiaryCount = addresses.length;
    for (uint i = 0; i < beneficiaryCount; i++) {

      uint weight = weights[i];

      addBeneficiary(addresses[i], weight);
      totalWeight += weight;
    }

    AssetCreated(_usagePrice, addresses, weights);
  }

  function getUsagePrice() constant returns (uint) {
    return usagePrice;
  }

  event BeneficiaryPaid(address addr, uint amount);

  function pay() payable onlyOwner {
    require(msg.value >= usagePrice);

    uint beneficiaryCount = beneficiaries.length;
    for (uint i = 0; i < beneficiaryCount; i++) {

      Beneficiary memory beneficiary = beneficiaries[i];

      uint weight = beneficiary.weight;
      address addr = beneficiary.addr;

      uint amount = (weight * usagePrice) / totalWeight;

      uint GAS_LIMIT = 4000000;
      addr.transfer.gas(GAS_LIMIT)(amount);
      BeneficiaryPaid(addr, amount);
    }
  }

  struct Beneficiary {
    address addr;
    uint weight;
  }

  function addBeneficiary(address addr, uint weight) onlyOwner {
    beneficiaries.push(Beneficiary({
        addr: addr,
        weight: weight
    }));
  }

}
```

How can I transfer money to the user addresses from the contract?

Comment: Looking at https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xdd6c0059b330dc25d1179dd6d93d843077f9af57389f1f9e07584c23ad57dff9, it seems that both transfer were done correctly. The second is to https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xbc965738eabb38d15dc5d0b63ec1420eab5df2bc#internaltx you should look at the "Internal Transaction" tab, there's a line where "Parent Hash" is 0xdd6c0059b330dc... the block is 1287872 the transfer for 0.05402... Ether.

Comment: @Ismael thanks. So the ETH was added to account 0xbC965738eAbb38d15dc5d0B63Ec1420EAb5df2BC? I just have to  look at *internal* transactions, and not transactions or the MetaMask wallet? :)

Comment: Yes, usually "internal transactions" are not tracked by wallets because no easy interface exist to access them yet.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks! This solves my problem. If you want you can add your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your [transaction 0xdd6c0059b330dc...](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xdd6c0059b330dc25d1179dd6d93d843077f9af57389f1f9e07584c23ad57dff9) both transfer were done correctly.

For example the second transfer is to [address 0xbc965738eabb38...](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xbc965738eabb38d15dc5d0b63ec1420eab5df2bc#internaltx), you should look at the "Internal Transaction" tab, there's a line where "Parent Hash" is `0xdd6c0059b330dc...` and block is `1287872` for an amount of 0.05402... Ether.

Usually "internal transactions" are not tracked by most wallets because it requires processing each transaction, and there's no public api to access them.